# Parse list of numbers from "dirty" string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string with integers in it which are separated by an arbitrary number and kind of symbols, e.g.:

fr365.43//236hu

and want to convert it into a list of the numbers 365, 43 and 236. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression you can extract the numbers from the 'dirty' string

```
var r = new Regex(@"\d+");
var result = r.Matches("fr365.43//236hu");
foreach (Match match in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
// outputs 365 then 43 then 236
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/b9712a7w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the following pattern:

```
(\d+)
```

Then convert to int.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s ="fr365.43//236hu";
string result = s.Split(s.Where(x=>!char.IsDigit(x))
                 .Select(x=>x).ToArray())
                 .Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

The result is an IEnumerable containing the following:
365
43
236

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` method, if you have more separators you should include them too:

```
str.Split('.','/').Select(x => x.All(char.IsDigit))
   .Select(int.Parse)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to extract integer numbers from the string:

```
var res = Regex.Split(str, @"\D+").Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```